# Android FusedLocationProviderClient not working

Tags: android, google-maps, google-location-services, fusedlocationproviderclient

I am using FusedLocationProviderClient to get the current location. In a particular case, user driving and device screen off, so the location service is stopped.
The service is working well in these cases below:

- Walking and Screen off
- Driving and Screen on

Please help me

**Thanks. I resolved this. It's my mistake when using the ModelView lifecycle. It will be stop the observe if the owner stops **

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the issue and what you have tried so far?

Comment: @smga08 thanks for the reply. It's my mistake when using the ModelView lifecycle.